# Asp.net MVC3 map route: add a prefix before the {id}

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have a route handle url like `http://..../controller/details/abc_1234`. I want to route the following url to the previous one too:

```
http://..../controller/abc/1234
```

It seems the following code doesn't work?

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
    "abc",
    "{controller}/abc/{id}",
    new { controller = "controller", action = "Details", id = "abc_{id}" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", 
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "controller", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    routes.MapRoute(
    "abc",
    "{controller}/{action}/{key}_{id}",
    new { controller = "controller" }
);
```

where your action would look like:

```
    public virtual ActionResult Details(string key, string id)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this with a action called `abc`

routes.MapRoute(
        "abc",
        "{controller}/abc/{id}",
        new { controller = "controller", action = "abc", id = "abc_{id}" }
    );
```

Comment: But I don't have an action named "abc". I need the url be rerouted to `details` action.

Comment: you can create an action called abc and call details action from the abc action

Comment: Yes, this will work after remove the `'abc_'` in the default parameter. Is it possible to handle it in the MapRoute function so no need to create an another controller?